# laravel 5.5.34 Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::userprofile()

Tags: laravel

**view.blade.php**

```
<a href="/userprofile/{{ $user->id }}"> Profile/>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/userprofile/{user_id}', 'AdminController@userprofile'));
```

**AdminController**

```
Class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function userprofile($user_id)
    {
        $exists = DB::table('user_profile')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
        //..
    }
     //..
}
```

**Error**

> Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::userprofile()

I got this argument missing error, which I cannot figure out where the mistake is.

Can anybody point out? Thx a lot!

Comment: is user id defined?. can you see it in the url?

Comment: Have you got another route pointing to `AdminController@userprofile` by chance?

Comment: check by changing your `view` <a href="/userprofile/1"> Profile</a> if it is work then your `{{ $user->id }}` is not sending id properly

Comment: Thank you, guys for your advice. Ross got it right, I mistakenly called AdminController@userprofile in another route.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in view file from

```
<a href="/userprofile/{{ $user->id }}"> Profile/>
```

TO

```
<a href="{{ url('userprofile/'. $user->id) }}"> Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{ url('userprofile/'. $user->id) }}"> Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys for your advice.

Ross got it right, I mistakenly called AdminController@userprofile in another route.

Other answers may be relevant in some cases. Appreciate your inputs.